# jQuery selection in chain does not work

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to select a checkbox, highlight the row that the checkbox is in and then update the value of a pick list field in that same row.  What I have isn't working well so far...

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.record_table tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row")
            $(':checkbox').siblings('td')
            $(this).val('Saab 95');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle would help us help you...

Comment: Can you explain your problem in a bit detail? Maybe add a Plunk or Fiddle?

Comment: Oh... sorry.  Here is a link to my Fiddle..https://jsfiddle.net/lizzyd/9z2usL5q/  The third column with the pick list value should change when the checkbox is selected and it should also be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

To select an element, you can't just set the `val` of the `select` element - although you can use that to **Retrieve** it.

What you need to do is find the `option` that you want to be selected and mark it's `selected` attribute as true.

Here:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
row.addClass("highlight_row");
row.find('td select.carSelect').find("option[value=saab]").attr("selected", true);
```

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/9bs0akxw/)